# CMake add_custom_command DEPENDS on filenames that are in a `space` separated string

Tags: cmake, makefile

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT my_output.out
  COMMAND ${MY_TOOL} ${PARAMETERS}
  DEPENDS ${MY_OBJECT_FILES}
  VERBATIM)
```

I have the above `add_custom_command` in my cmake that `DEPENDS` on filenames (`MY_OBJECT_FILES`) that are generated from a list as:

```
set(MY_OBJECT_FILES "")
foreach(config ${CONFIGURATIONS})
  set(MY_OBJECT_FILES "${MY_OBJECT_FILES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated-file-${config}.o")
endforeach()
```

The above `foreach` loop generates a string that contains the names of all the object files separated by `whitespace`. But when the cmake built the built.make it puts extra `\` in the beginning and before each `whitespace` and it messes up with the build.

It looks like this:

```
my_output.out: \ /home/user/project/build/generated-file-config1.o\ /home/user/project/build/generated-file-config2.o\ /home/user/project/build/generated-file-config3.o\ 
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --blue --bold --progress-dir=/home/user/project/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Generating my_output.out"
    /opt/bin/my_tool -parameter1=5 -parameter2=4
```

How do I resolve this and provide the `DEPENDS` with proper `whitespace` separated list of files?

Answer (score 0):

`separate_arguments(MY_OBJECT_FILES UNIX_COMMAND "${MY_OBJECT_FILES}")`

Solves the problem.